# Am I encouraged to ask my question on multiple SE QA Sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, cross-posting, support

Simply put. Sometimes I have a question that fits on more than one QA site.

Example: An *applescript* question could be asked in both *Ask Different* and *Stack Overflow*.

*Ask Different* should be the proper Site to ask the question, but *Stack Overflow* has a bigger community and a lot of support for *applescript* questions.

Is asking the same question on both sites encouraged? If not, what's the recommended approach?

Thank you in advance,

PS: Should I even be asking this question in *Meta Stack Exchange* instead of the AD or SO Meta Sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posting the same question on multiple sites at once is not allowed** (although sometimes people get away with it anyway, if it goes unnoticed).  The best option is to **post it first on whichever site you feel is most appropriate first**, and then see if it works well there.  If it does not, **the question can be migrated** to another site or simply be deleted and recreated elsewhere for further attempts.

Comment: I was looking for a reference in the domain about how to proceed. To you have a reference for that rule?

Comment: @sargas My reference would be the duplicate question, which is already listed for the question on the whole.

Comment: I just realized that duplicate IS part of the FAQ and, therefore, recognized as a rule. Thank you for the referral.